# OPENSHIFT + j_security_check problems

Tags: openshift

I have Java code with j_security_check that works on a local Tomcat + MySQL server.  I am not able to get it working on the Openshift Jboss (Tomcat) cartridge.

----web.xml code snippet:----

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Validate</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- Authorize the service and programmer roles -->
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<!-- Use form-based authentication to provide access -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/validation/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/validation/login_error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
```

--------META-INF/context.xml:-----

```
    <Context path="/musicStoreOTUser">
<Resource auth="Container"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
logAbandoned="true"
maxActive="100" 
maxIdle="30"
maxWait="10000"
name="jdbc/musicDB"
password="ask4_sgh"
removeAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://127.7.245.2:3306/mydb"
username="admin1234"/>
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
connectionName="admin1234"
connectionPassword="ask4_sgh"
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://127.7.245.2:3306/mydb"
dataSourceName="jdbc/musicDB"
debug="99"
driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
roleNameCol="Rolename"
userCredCol="Password"
userNameCol="EmailAddress"
userRoleTable="RoleTable"
userTable="PassTable"/>
```

---

When I log in in the login form, I simply get Login incorrect.  No messages are logged in the jbossews.log file.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks,

Comment: Without any error message, I would check that the DB has been initialized with the same records as the local one. If the user is in both databases, you could perhaps find something in the `mysql.log` or tail all logs using `rhc tail <yourApp>` when trying to log in to see if there's anything relevant logged.

Comment: Hi Jiri, thank you for your thoughts!  Interestingly, the application creates the users and passwords in the credential tables.  It does not check against them somehow.  "mysql.log" shows gives no errors or other clues.  System.out.println do not show up in jbosswes.log.  How might I get the System.out.println messages to show up, any idea?  Appreciate any thoughts.